# Adding a sum of string to REGEXP_INSTR for tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I created a regex expression to return all different regions as names and it works fine.

Now what I'd like is, to have the result as they are now PLUS add an extra string for "All" that would include all region results together so when I use my parameter/filter I can either see region independently or all together.

Thanks in advance for your inputs

Here is my regex expression:
,CASE WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(t1.campaign_name, '(»ON)') <> 0 THEN 'Central'
WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(t1.campaign_name, '(Atlantic|»AT$|ATL|1567|»NL$|Newfoundland|2496)') <> 0 THEN 'Atlantic'
WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(t1.campaign_name, '(»BC|»PR|»AB)') <> 0 THEN 'West'
WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(t1.campaign_name, '(»QC)') <> 0 THEN 'Quebec'
WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(t1.campaign_name, '(»NT|Brand)') <> 0 THEN 'National'
WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(t1.Placement_name, '(»ON»)') <> 0 THEN 'Central'
WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(t1.Placement_name, '(QC)') <> 0 THEN 'Quebec'
WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(t1.site_name, '(Quebecor)') <> 0 THEN 'Quebec'
WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(t1.Placement_name, '(Alberta|BC|Prairies)') <> 0 THEN 'West'
ELSE 'Missing Region'

```
    END AS Region
```

FROM pdw.dfa_sum_gm t1

Here is the table result in tableau
DMA
Atlantic
Central
National
Quebec
West

I need an extra field "All"

Comment: What is the purpose? If you do not select any value, the filter is explicitly displayed as `(all)`. Adding is as a value will not help you since theres no such a value in the data. You need to copy the same daya and set this dimension's value to constant `All`, but I hope this is not what you want.

Comment: @astentx Im trying to add an ALL value because I use a DMA filter in the dashboard that only allows me to select one value, but it does not have an ALL value for when I need to see the whole country (which is different from National). Not sure how to add a picture of my dashboard to show you

Comment: I understand you, but you need some custom logic between dropdown and actual filtering, so this will not be simple `where region = <your selected item>`. I'm unsure this is possible. What about the `case` statement: it acts like some mapper, so it allows only one output value per one row. It will not allow you to solve the problem. Union your data with `All` as region and this will do the trick, but will repeat all the logic and double the dara.